# Schwarz–Pick theorem for one inequality with holomorphic function

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f(z)$ be holomorphic function in unit disc and $|f(z)| \le 1$. Prove that:

$$\left| \frac{f(z)-f(0)}{z} \right| \le \left| 1- \overline{f(z)}f(0) \right|$$

I would use Schwarz–Pick theorem as $$\frac{|f'(z)|}{1-|f(z)|^2} \le \frac{1}{1-|z|^2}$$. Is there any way to prove it only by using these inequality?

Comment: it's not what your asking for, but see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarz_lemma#Schwarz.E2.80.93Pick_theorem - the  1st inequality is proven using the same Schwarz lemma as the 2nd one

Comment: The Schwarz-Pick theorem is $|f(z)-f(w)|/|1-\overline{f(z)}f(w)|\le |z-w|/|1-\overline{z}w|$. The proof is just Schwarz' lemma, which in turn is just the maximum principle. Now your *first* inequality is the special case $w=0$, while your *second* inequality arises when you let $w\rightarrow z$.